# Echo not being executed before return response

Tags: php, laravel, return, echo

I have a really simple question. I have this Controller in my Laravel application, that returns a zip file download, depending on what the user selected. So far so good. I also have this echo just before the return:

```
echo "<script> alert('test') </script>";

return response()->download(public_path($fileName));
```

My question is: the "echo" is not being executed, but if i remove the return, it is executed.. isn't the "echo" supposed to execute before the return ? Why is it not being executed?

Answer (score 0):

`download()` forces browser to well... download given file, so there is no place to display echo text. You can use for example redirect to download page to firstly display alert box.

Comment: Yes.. i do know that.. My question is why is the echo not being executed BEFORE the download. I think that is pretty explicit in the question.

Comment: In php there is no before. Entire request is send to browser in same time. Download prepare it in the way that browser doesn't recognize it as page, but file.

Comment: There is no before ? What do you mean by that ? It appears that you are saying that PHP doens't follow the code sequence.

Comment: Echo in this context add some text to response body, but download at the end change it all to download a file. So there is no response body and within page where could be displayed.